# XMLHttpRequest.send() не читает ответ при коде != 200

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Суть проблемы: XMLHttpRequest не хочет считывать код ошибки и JSON содержимое ответа сервера в случае ошибки (н.р. код 502).

Пример:

```
const formData = new FormData();
const QHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
QHttp.open("POST", reqUrl, true);
QHttp.responseType = 'json';

QHttp.onerror = () => {console.log(QHttp.response, QHttp.status)}
QHttp.send(formData);
```

В консоль выводится: `null 0`, хотя тот же Postman получает все верно:

```
Status: 502 Bag Gateway Time: 65ms Size: 187 B
{
    "message": "too long request 277188118 > 209715200!"
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Дополнено:
Похоже, что проблема не в кодах ответа а в том, что XMLHttpRequest неверно отрабатывает, если сервер не принимает от него данные, а сразу возвращает ему код ошибки с сообщением.

Comment: Возможно стоит [проверить ответ в QHttp.onload](https://learn.javascript.ru/xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. onload() вообще не вывывается при ошибке, что соотвествует поведению, описанному в документации:
`The load event is fired when an XMLHttpRequest transaction completes successfully.`

Comment: С точки зрения xhr 502 это не ошибка. Может у вас проблема с CORS? Вы запрашиваете урл с другого домена?

Comment: нет, ресурс локальный. Сообщений о cors нет, есть только о разрыве соединения.
POST /url bla bla/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

Comment: Вы указали `responseType = 'json'`, а это означает, что если сервер в своей ошибке 502 пришлёт не json, то браузер не сможет распарсить ответ и выдаст вам null

Comment: Правда, не очень очевидно, почему при этом status должен быть нулём, но, если я правильно понимаю спецификацию, оно должно просто брать status из response, а если response это null, то получается, что и status взять тоже неоткуда

Answer (score 0):

```
const formData = new FormData();
const QHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
QHttp.open('POST', reqUrl, true);
QHttp.responseType = 'json';
QHttp.send(formData);

QHttp.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (QHttp.status === 200) {
    //сделать что-то
  } else {
    console.log(QHttp.status);
  }
});
```

Comment: Добрый день! Так ведь это же тот же onload().

Comment: @ГеоргийЖаворонков Добрый день. Вы попробовали? Не решило вашу проблему?

Comment: Да пробовал по-разному. Возможно, XMLHttpRequest видит это как разрыв соединения. В консоли висит сообщение POST /url bla bla/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

Comment: @ГеоргийЖаворонков Вам принципиально использовать именно XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Не обязательно его, но желательно чистый js.

Comment: Можно использовать более современный fetch. Кстати а сервер куда вы отправляете данные, он настроен на получение json ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144642/discussion-between-elmir-and--).

Comment: Не знал про fetch. Попробую его ;)
Странно, что при запросе "AJAX" о нем не упоминается

Comment: Не получится в чате. 1) почему-то опять же отдельный ресурс 2) Нужна репутация именно на этом ресурсе, Чтоо??
По теме: опробовал fetch(url, {method: "POST", body: formData}).then((r) => {console.log(r);});
Та же тема с net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED и вдобавок Failed to fetch